# Custom TabItem properties (TabItem.Content and TabItem.Header)

Tags: c#, wpf, inheritance, casting

I'm trying to inherit `MyTabItem` from [System.Windows.Controls.TabItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.tabitem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class. The problem is, that original `TabItem` has properties of generic `object` type:

```
public object Header;
public object Content;
```

I'm trying to hide those properties in my derived class with different types.

```
public class MyTabItem: TabItem
{
    public new MyTabHeader Header;
    public new MyTabContent Content;
}
```

This way, I can access `MyTabItem.Header` and `MyTabItem.Content` without type casting.

The idea is pretty decent and code compiles correctly. However when application starts I see empty controls (no error is reported). When I remove those lines and use base class properties, it works fine.

[image]

Of course I could add two additional properties which would internally return casted `(MyTabHeader)Header` or `(MyTabContent)Header`, but it seems to be a little redundant.

I'm asking if there is any other way to correctly implement those properties, so they actually work in my application.

Comment: `The idea is pretty decent` - Sorry, no. Whatever **data** you might need to *store*, the UI is not the right place for it. The UI's responsibility is to **show** data, not to *store* it. Create a proper DataModel and use proper DataBinding. You don't need `MyTabItem` or any of that.

Comment: Why do you think I use 'MyTabItem' to store data? It only includes methods to manipulate UI (hide textboxes, reload images). Data is actually stored in different Model classes and properly binded via DataContext.

Comment: see Mark Feldman's answer. It is the correct answer, which I'm too lazy to write myself, and I also wrote several times already in SO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This runs completely counter to how WPF was designed to be used. Your XAML objects are supposed to be loosely bound to data, in the vast majority of cases you shouldn't even need to create a custom control. The fact that you are doing this, and then trying to replace the members with type-safe versions of your own, means your view code and your view logic code are no longer separated, and that is going to create you a world of headache down the track.

If you need dynamic tabbing then one way to do it is to first declare an abstract class representing your pages and to derive your page types from it:

```
public interface IBasePage
{
    string Header { get; }
}

public class MyPageA : ViewModelBase, IBasePage
{
    public string Header { get { return "Page A"; } }
}

public class MyPageB : ViewModelBase, IBasePage
{
    public string Header { get {return "Page B";} }
}

public class MyPageC : ViewModelBase, IBasePage
{
    public string Header { get {return "Page C";} }
}
```

Your view model (which is what your window DataContext should be set to) should then contain a collection of the tabbed pages you wish to display:

```
public class MyViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private IEnumerable<IBasePage> _MyPages = new List<IBasePage>(){
        new MyPageA(),
        new MyPageB(),
        new MyPageC()
    };
    public IEnumerable<IBasePage> MyPages {get {return this._MyPages;}}
}
```

The tab control in your XAML is then loosely bound to this and should contain a style for your TabItem (so it know what text to use for the header etc) and DataTemplates so that it knows how to render each of the page types you've created:

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyPages}" SelectedItem="{Binding MyPages[0], Mode=OneTime}">
    <TabControl.Resources>

        <!-- TabItem style -->
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
            <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Header}" />
        </Style>

        <!-- Content templates -->
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MyPageA}">
            <TextBlock Text="This is page A" />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MyPageB}">
            <TextBlock Text="This is page B" />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MyPageC}">
            <TextBlock Text="This is page C" />
        </DataTemplate>

    </TabControl.Resources>
</TabControl>
```

The end result is a regular tab control that is completely data driven and is bound to your already-strongly-typed models:

[image]

Comment: It turns out, I've been overcomplicating things. I did what you suggested: ItemsSource binded to `ObservableCollection<MyTabItem>`. Also I set up two setters, for Header and Content to `MyTabItem.Header` and `MyTabItem.Content`. `MyTabItem` is now just plain View Model and no longer UI control.

Comment: Sounds good, in that case you can probably just use a single page class and set up your DataTemplates to the Content property. It can be a difficult mind-set to break out of, especially after decades of doing things the Winforms way. And it's not helped much by the fact that MS specifically wrote a lot of code to help people do things the old way in order to facilitate in the transition away from it.